# Is Ubuntu Server OS 12.04.2 fully compatible and supported by Bulldozer based AMD Opteron 3280?

Tags: 12.04, server, 64-bit, hardware, hardware-certification

**Questions**

1) Is Ubuntu Server OS 12.04.2 fully compatible and supports with Bulldozer based AMD Opteron 3280?

2) Is it compulsory to use Ubuntu Server certified hardware vendors and models? But my hardware vendor ( fujitsu primergy mx130 s2 server) is not in [Ubuntu Server certified hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/) , will this make any kernel panic errors or system instability during long run?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases hardware incompatibilities are rare, and tend to often be with specific hardware components. Chances are your server would work, even if its not in the certified hardware list - the list simply means that someone tested to make sure everything *does* work, and probably ship with an installed, configured version of the OS, with all the necessary drivers.

It very likely will not crash.I've seen other reports that it works fine. Haven't seen any mentions of kernel panics or system instability. Ubuntu gets installed on a wide array of hardware and usually works, so this should be a non issue

On the other hand apparently there's [sometimes a problem](http://www.iokom.com/drupal/node/15) with the built in graphics adaptor and the default settings - especially if you need fglrx. The link recommends installing ssh during the initial install (something you should do anyway) in case this happens. Should the system boot with no video output, it may be necessary to use ssh or a rescue console to fix the drivers. 
 It may be neccessary to backup `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, and purge, and reboot and reinstall `fglrx` and `fglrx-amdcccle`, then rebuild a new xorg file with `sudo aticonfig --initial`. I'd note this probably wouldn't be an issue with a server setup that dosen't use any X related functions.